# problem with installing photoshop

Tags: apt, wine, mono, photoshop

[image]
I've tried install photoshop cc in ubuntu 20.04 but I got some error in my terminal.
First I wanted to install via wine but I got this:

```
 "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." I can't resolve this problem.
```

Then I visited this repo and led by guide published there https://github.com/Gictorbit/photoshopCClinux
First error "please install mono and gecko packages then click on OK button, do not change Windows version from Windows 7" Ok further I tried install mono packages but bad luck. this time I got

```
Err:1 http://mirror.vorboss.net/ubuntu-archive focal/universe amd64 mono-runtime-sgen amd64 6.8.0.105+dfsg-2
  403  Forbidden
```

Please explain me how it work? or if I really need photoshop can i uninstall ubuntu? thanks a lot!

UPDATE
thank to all who answered me. at this time i still trying install photoshop. so i did what me recommended. I install necessery utilites - wine, winetricks
during installation all works well https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzcVn.jpg
but then i got this

"it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32""

and i did it https://i.stack.imgur.com/inbmO.jpg
all the same an error occured and now problem with broken packages https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQD5z.jpg

Maybe someone explain me how can i this unfortunate photoshop install? thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] to add the output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: The version of Wine in their repository is broken. You will have to [restore default repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories), and use the version of Wine in the official repositories. It is an issue with your wine installation, and not with photoshop.

Comment: Did you tried some of this steps listed [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing WineHQ repository for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS works normally.

So your problem is caused by broken mirror at `http://mirror.vorboss.net/ubuntu-archive`. You have to switch from it to Main Server or other server by using Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) for this purpose.

Then fix other broken repositories and keys by

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 23E7166788B63E1E

sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:andrew-crew-kuznetsov/xneur-stable
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:atareao/flameshot
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

And finally run normal package lists update and package upgrade procedures by using below commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Why these particular PPAs? Are they known to cause issues?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I have just OCRed OP's [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJBn1.jpg). They have 404s.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i did right what u wrote.
1) change server https://i.imgur.com/h04eBoY.png
2)  invoked commands that u wrote 
https://i.imgur.com/JyzRBXf.jpg 
https://i.imgur.com/3eHEsCc.png
everything is done smoothly.
3) then tried again install photoshop according to the manual https://i.imgur.com/ayrZY1c.jpg 
4) and hell starts https://i.imgur.com/dU9Mrhr.jpg
maybe is other way install wine?

Comment: Please try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install aptitude; sudo aptitude install wine-stable winehq-stable`. Please do not post images, use pastebin for long text outputs.

Comment: I was able to run the wine but the photoshop didn't install https://i.imgur.com/CAH6bUr.jpg

Comment: I do not know which script you use and from where. Reproducible way seems to be using [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-3066-Adobe_Photoshop_CC_2015.html).